# Is there a way to copy ArcGIS Pro Python environments to another computer?

Tags: python, arcgis-pro, installation

I develop Python script tools in ArcGIS Pro for my company. My Python environment has multiple additional and custom packages installed. I'm installing ArcGIS Pro on other computers for the company, and would like to duplicate the python environment from the first machine, preferably without having to reinstall everything manually.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Since you state that you have multiple custom packages installed you must be working with a cloned Python environment.  Have you tried making a copy of your cloned environment output folder to another computer and pointing the ArcGIS Pro Python interpreter at that copy?

Comment: I am working with a cloned environment. I copied the folder across, put it in the same place, named it the same thing. Although I can add it as an environment, I get a "Broken environment, cannot activate" warning.

Comment: https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#building-identical-conda-environments